# border-radius firefox not working

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to get the border-radius property to work on a table in Firefox. It works fine in chrome and I don't care about IE 8 and lower.

My CSS:

```
table.tableCenter{
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
```

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the issue as well.
https://jsfiddle.net/1o6mzvff/

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I just realized I have some css twice, ignore that. It still doesn't work after fixing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like `border-radius` is not working on a `<table>`: Try adding `display:block;` to `table.tableCenter{ }` and you get the round border.

Suggestions:

1. Get rid of the table ;-)
2. Or (untested): Use a `<div>` instead of `<table>`, and use `display:table` (plus `display:table-row` and `table-cell` for the nested `<tr>`/`<td>`'s which need to become `<div>`'s as well for HTML-validity).

I would go for the first option, cause it looks like you're using the table for layout only, which is bad markup anyway ;-)

Comment: I agree with you. I got a div border-radius to work properly in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I took out my trusty Visual Page (an extremely archaic web page editor) and I did this and it worked just fine:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html;CHARSET=iso-8859-1">
    <META NAME="GENERATOR" Content="Visual Page 2.0 for Windows">
    <TITLE>untitled</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P>
<TABLE BORDER="0" WIDTH="100%" STYLE="border-radius : 15px; border : 1px solid black;">
    <TR>
        <TD WIDTH="33%">adfasdfsads</TD>
        <TD WIDTH="33%">asfsdfsadfasdfsaf</TD>
        <TD WIDTH="34%">safsadfsaf</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD WIDTH="33%">sdfsafsdfsadf</TD>
        <TD WIDTH="33%">sadfsadfsdfsaf</TD>
        <TD WIDTH="34%">sfdsafsdfds</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD WIDTH="33%">sadfsdfasfdas</TD>
        <TD WIDTH="33%">safsdfsadf</TD>
        <TD WIDTH="34%">safdsdfsdf</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Do you have your DOCTYPE at the start?  That can affect things sometimes. The same holds true for the HTTP-EQUIV Meta command.  Also, sometimes doing these things in the STYLE attribute will work when the CSS does not work.  I know - not supposed to do that.  I think why this happens is you get a conflict somewhere in your CSS and then the STYLE command takes precedent so it straightens out the problem.  Unknown really.

Comment: This is not the issue, thanks though. I did not have the doc-type included +1

Comment: HTML 3.2 - are you serious? ;-)

Comment: Hey!  He was using tables!  VP still will create web pages that work in all browsers.  Heh.  I've written a program to take the code and convert it to using CSS.  I'd jump ship to a newer editor (I have Dreamweaver, WebPlus, and several others) but the simplicity of VP keeps me using it and my converter does all of the heavy lifting.  My convert program lays everything out in MVC format, creates the CSS files, puts all commands in to use jQuery, standard Javascript functions, and more.  So I do some standard stuff and it does the rest. :-)

Answer (score 0):

amm i think you have to add `border: 1px solid #fff;`

Comment: This will add a border to the element. The asker is trying to create a border-radius.